# Discrete Math question - cookies

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Simple math question:

How many ways are there to choose $12$ cookies if there are $5$ varieties?

It was wrong in my homework after I tried $5^{12}$.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is the same as asking "How many ways are there to deposit $12$ identical balls into $5$ distinguishable boxes?"  In this case, the balls are your choices, and the boxes are the $5$ cookie varieties.

Hint:  See Theorem Two at the link below.  It's quite accessible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Answer (score 1):

Stars and Bars will get you the answer. I will offer a generating function derivation of the solution as well, as another way to look at things.

With a generating function, we use a geometric series to index. So for each type of cookie, we could have none of that cookie, one cookie, two cookies, etc. This could be modeled as $1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + ... = \frac{1}{x}$, where given $x^{i}$, the $i$ term represents the quantity of that type of cookie. Notice we have a formal geometric series.

Since there are no other constraints on the cookie types and we have five types of cookies, we get $f(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{5}}$. Using our binomial identity, we search for the coefficient of $x^{12}$ which is $\binom{12 + 5 - 1}{12}$.